# watson discovery query -- result set not as expected

Tags: watson, discovery

I would like to query the discovery service 'news collection' and I am using this query command.

```
discovery.query({ environment_id: ‘my env id’,
              collection_id: ‘my coll id’,
              “count”: 10,
              “return”: “title,enrichedTitle.text”,
              “query”: “dieter zetsche”,
              “aggregations”: [ “term(docSentiment.type:2)“]
            },  function(err, response) { …
```

I am expecting the following response structure

```
{
    “matching_results”: 7607,
    “aggregations”: [
       {...}
    ],
    “passages”: [],
    “results”: [
       {...}
    ]
}
```

but I get only the response without the ‘aggregation’ -- any recommendation???
like this

```
{"matching_results":7603,
   "results":[
      {"id":"....
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the JSON object name for Sentiment Analysis has been **changed** from **docSentiment** to **sentiment**

More details here: https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/discovery/migrate-nlu.html#overview-of-major-changes